# Implicit method group conversion gotcha

Tags: c#, delegates

I am wondering why the output of the given code (execute it in LinqPad)

```
void Main() {
    Compare1((Action)Main).Dump();
    Compare2(Main).Dump();
}

bool Compare1(Delegate x) {
    return x == (Action)Main;
}

bool Compare2(Action x) {
    return x == Main;
}
```

is always:

```
 False
 True
```

I have naively expected it to be `True` in both cases.

Comment: Changing `Compare1` to use `return x == (Delegate)(Action)Main;` makes it return `true`. Not sure why though.

Comment: FYI: I asked a relative question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939350/implicit-method-group-conversion-gotcha-part-2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how it looks when compiled to IL and then decompiled back to C#. Note that in both cases there's `new Action(Main)` - a new reference object (delegate) with pointer to actual method stored inside.

```
private static void Main()
{
    Program.Compare1(new Action(Program.Main)).Dump();
    Program.Compare2(new Action(Program.Main)).Dump();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static bool Compare1(Delegate x)
{
   return x == new Action(Program.Main);
}

private static bool Compare2(Action x)
{
   return x == new Action(Program.Main);
}
```

If then we take a look into CIL, the former uses `ceq` (reference comparison) and the latter uses `call bool [mscorlib]System.Delegate::op_Equality(class [mscorlib]System.Delegate, class [mscorlib]System.Delegate)` to compare delegates.

First returns `false` because actions wrapping your delegates are two distinct reference objects.

Second returns `true` as the equality operator implemented on the `Delegate` class compares actual targets inside wrappers (actions).

Answer (score 7):

The `false` result is related to the fact that the Compare1() method performs reference comparison on two different object (compilator shows the corresponding warning):

```
IL_0001:  ldarg.0
IL_0002:  ldnull
IL_0003:  ldftn      instance void ConsoleApplication1.Test::Main()
IL_0009:  newobj     instance void [System.Core]System.Action::.ctor(object,
                                                                   native int)
IL_000e:  ceq <<reference comparison
```

You can avoid the issue using the following code:

```
bool Compare1(Delegate x) {
    return x == (Delegate)((Action)Main);
}
```