# Implicit method group conversion gotcha (Part 2)

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading

Simplified from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938461/implicit-method-group-conversion-gotcha) and got rid of possible affect from LinqPad(no offsensive), a simple console application like this:

```
public class Program
{
    static void M() { }    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action a = new Action(M);
        Delegate b = new Action(M);
        Console.WriteLine(a == b);      //got False here
        Console.Read();
    }        
}
```

The "false" results from the operator `ceq` in CIL of the code above(visit the original question for details). So my questions are:

(1) Why `==` is translating to `ceq` instead of `call Delegate Equals`?

Here I don't care about the (un)wrapping between Delegate and Action. At the very last, when evaluating `a == b`, a is of type `Action` while b is a `Delegate`. From the spec:

> 7.3.4 Binary operator overload resolution
>
> An operation of the form x op y, where op is an overloadable binary operator, x is an expression
>   of type X, and y is an expression of type Y, is processed as follows:
>
> • The set of candidate user-defined operators provided by X and Y for
>   the operation operator op(x, y) is determined. The set consists of the
>   union of the candidate operators provided by X and the candidate
>   operators provided by Y, each determined using the rules of §7.3.5. If
>   X and Y are the same type, or if X and Y are derived from a common
>   base type, then shared candidate operators only occur in the combined
>   set once.
>
> •  If the set of candidate user-defined operators is not
>   empty, then this becomes the set of candidate operators for the
>   operation. Otherwise, the predefined binary operator op
>   implementations, including their lifted forms,  become the set of
>   candidate operators for the operation. The predefined implementations
>   of a given operator are specified in the description of the operator
>   (§7.8 through §7.12).
>
> •  The overload resolution rules of §7.5.3 are
>   applied to the set of candidate operators to select the best operator
>   with respect to the argument list (x, y), and this operator becomes
>   the result of the overload resolution process. If overload resolution
>   fails to select a single best operator, a binding-time error occurs.
>
> 7.3.5 Candidate user-defined operators
>
> Given a type T and an operation operator op(A), where op is an overloadable operator and A is an argument list, the set of candidate user-defined operators provided by
>   T for operator op(A) is determined as follows:
>
> •  Determine the type
>   T0. If T is a nullable type, T0 is its underlying type, otherwise T0
>   is equal to T.
>
> •  For all operator op declarations in T0 and all lifted
>   forms of such operators, if at least one operator is applicable
>   (§7.5.3.1) with respect to the argument list A, then the set of
>   candidate operators consists of all such applicable operators in T0.
>
> • Otherwise, if T0 is object, the set of candidate operators is empty.
>
> • Otherwise, the set of candidate operators provided by T0 is the set
>   of candidate operators provided by the direct base class of T0, or the
>   effective base class of T0 if T0 is a type parameter.

From the spec, a and b have a same base class `Delegate`, obviously the operator rule `==` defined in `Delegate` should be applied here(the operator == invokes Delegate.Equals essentially). But now it looks like the candidate list of user-defined operators is empty and at last `Object ==` is applied.

(2) Should(Does) the FCL code obey the C# language spec? If no, my first question is meaningless because something is specially treated. And then we can answer all of these questions using "oh, it's a special treatment in FCL, they can do something we can't. The spec is for outside programmers, don't be silly".

Comment: That's why it's best to use `Equals` when expecting value-type semantics. Because of (potentially) broken operator overloads.

Comment: @Groo: Exactly. And by the way I got compile warning for the code in the question `Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right hand side to type 'System.Action'`.

Comment: It's definitely to do with the special treatment of delegates in general, as trying the same thing with a user-defined class hierarchy calls the custom `==` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of operators: user-defined operators and predefined operators. Section 7.3.5 "Candidate user-defined operators" does not apply to predefined operators.
For example, the operators on `decimal` look like user-defined operators in a decompiler, but C# treats them as predefined operators and applies numeric promotion to them (numeric promotion is not applied to user-defined operators).

Section 7.10.8 "Delegate equality operators" defines `operator ==(Delegate, Delegate)` as a predefined operator, so I'd think that all the rules about user-defined operators don't apply to this operator (although this isn't 100% clear in the spec as in this case, the predefined operator doesn't apply whenever the user-defined operator would).

```
Every delegate type implicitly provides the following predefined comparison operators: 
bool operator ==(System.Delegate x, System.Delegate y);
bool operator !=(System.Delegate x, System.Delegate y);
```

But `System.Delegate` itself is not considered a delegate type, so the only candidate for overload resolution is `operator ==(object, object)`.

Comment: Then why does the output change to `True` if he changes to `Console.WriteLine((Delegate)a == b);`? Now the compile-time type of neither operand is a "delegate type" (since as you say non-concrete class `System.Delegate` is not a "delegate type" itself), but still the delegate-type overload is used. (I just found this thread because my own question [Overload resolution on operator == with variant generic delegate types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408165/) has been linked to this one.)

Answer (score 6):

Compiler works very different and unusual with delegates. There are a lot of implicit handling. **Notice, that 'common base type' rule in this guide is applied to 'user-defined operators'. Delegates are internal and system.** For example, you can  write `Action a = M;` instead of `Action a = new Action(M);`. And you can add `a += M;` after that. Check what happens in CIL, it is interesting at a first time.

Further more: it is dangerous and non-trivial to compare delegates. Every delegate is actually multicast delegate. You can add several function pointers to the same delegate. Does delegates `[L(); M(); N();]` equals to delegate `[M();]` ? Function pointer contains class instance (for instance method). Does `[a.M();]` equals to `[b.M();]`? All that depends on a case, and comparison implementation requires to step through invocation list.

Delegates inheritance from common base type Delegate is implicit and this problem you can face in another scenarios, e.g. generic constraint: you can not specify Delegate as a constraint to generic parameter T. Here compiler explicitly declines this. The same about creating your own classes, inherited from Delegate.

This is answer to both questions - 'Delegate' is not purely FCL, it is tightly coupled with compiler. If you really want Microsoft's delegate comparer behavior - just call explicitly `Equals(a, b)`

Comment: This was a question about the language specification, and I don't think "This is compiler magic" is a sufficient answer to those kind of questions.

Comment: And yes, comparing multicast delegates is non-trivial, but the C# specification clearly defines how it works.

Answer (score 5):

> warning CS0253: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right hand side to type 'System.Action'

That is the warning you get for that C# code.  Don't ignore that warning, the C# team was well aware that the code they generated for this comparison was unexpected.  They didn't *have* to generate that code, they could easily have done what you expected.  Like this code does:

```
Module Module1
    Sub M()
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim a = New Action(AddressOf M)
        Dim b = DirectCast(New Action(AddressOf M), [Delegate])
        Console.WriteLine(a = b)      ''got True here
        Console.Read()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Which generates almost the same MSIL, except that instead of `ceq` you get:

```
 IL_001d:  call bool [mscorlib]System.Delegate::op_Equality(class [mscorlib]System.Delegate,
                                                            class [mscorlib]System.Delegate)
```

Which what you hoped the C# code would do.  That was VB.NET code, in case you didn't recognize it.  Otherwise the reason that Microsoft keeps two major managed languages around, even though they have very similar capabilities.  But with very different usability choices.  Whenever there was more than one way to generate code, the C# team consistently chose for *performance*, the VB.NET team consistently for *convenience*.

And performance certainly is the key here, comparing delegate objects is **expensive**.  The rules are spelled out in Ecma-335, section II.14.6.1.  But you can reason it out for yourself, there is a lot of checking to do.  It needs to check if the delegate target object is compatible.  And for each argument it must check if the value is convertible.  Expense that the C# team does not want to hide.

And doesn't, you get the warning to remind you that they made the unintuitive choice. .

Comment: The most surprising thing in C# is that while both `(Action)a == (Action)b` and `(Delegate)a == (Delegate)b` goes to delegate value comparison, the case `(Action)a == (Delegate)b` goes to reference equality check (with compile-time warning). This is unnatural, in particular because `Action` is implicitly convertible (by reference conversion) to `Delegate`.

Comment: You got half the bounty for your answer (which is good). But I still feel that the C# compiler does something that is not easily seen to be in agreement with the C# Language Specification, and I wanted an answer about that. Also see linked thread _Overload resolution on operator `==` with variant generic delegate types_. But I agree that comparing multicast delegates is expensive, and checking reference equality is very cheap, and that there might be different philosophies in C# and VB.NET for what to "optimize".

Answer (score -1):

The key here is that the `==` operator and the `Equals` method for the `Delegate` type are two different things. For reference types, the `==` looks to see if both references point to the same object unless the `==` operator is overridden (see: [== Operator (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).

Since you are creating two different `Action` objects, even though they internally invoke the same method, they are different objects in different locations in memory, and are not of a value or `string` type, so `==` is in this case a `ReferenceEquals`, and does not invoke the `Delegate.Equals` method, which has been overridden to see if the two objects do the same thing. For reference types other than `string`, this is the default behavior of `==` or `Equals`.

Comment: For reference types, the `==` operator does whatever it's defined to do for that particular type.  Many types do not perform a reference equality check.

Comment: I've added the 'unless the "==" operator is overridden' clause to my statement. The key is that the "==" op is generally used to compare reference, and the Equals method is generally use to compare value.

Comment: @highphilospher: I'm undoing the downvote, but C# doesn't share the Java's philosophy of `==` being used for reference equality.  Mostly it isn't.  If you want reference equality, use the `object.ReferenceEquals` static method.

Comment: I do find in the MSDN that the "expected behavior" for "==" is this: "For predefined value types, the equality operator (==) returns true if the values of its operands are equal, false otherwise. For reference types other than string, == returns true if its two operands refer to the same object. For the string type, == compares the values of the strings."  Other people override it to do value base comparisons too, but this is the "default" implementation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That's the default, yes.  But it's also the default for the `Equals` method.

Comment: btw, another very common reference type where `operator==` is redefined is `System.Type`.  Pretty much all `System.Reflection` classes do too.