# Overload resolution on operator == with variant generic delegate types

Tags: c#, delegates, operator-overloading, overload-resolution

What are the precise rules for overload resolution with `==` between two expressions of delegate type?

Consider the following code (where `using System;` is needed):

```
static class ProgramA
{
    static void TargetMethod(object obj)
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Action<object> instance1 = TargetMethod;
        Action<object> instance2 = TargetMethod;

        Action<string> a1 = instance1;
        Action<Uri> a2 = instance2;

        Console.WriteLine((object)a1 == (object)a2);
        Console.WriteLine((Delegate)a1 == (Delegate)a2);
        Console.WriteLine((Action<object>)a1 == (Action<object>)a2);

        Console.WriteLine(a1 == a2);  // warning CS0253: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right hand side to type 'System.Action<string>'
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

`instance1` and `instance2` are two separate instances of the same run-time type, the generic `Action<in T>` which is **contravariant** in `T`. Those instances are distinct but `Equals` since they the have same targets.

`a1` and `a2` are the same as `instance1` and `instance2`, but because of the contravariance of `Action<in T>` there exist *implicit* reference conversions from `Action<object>` to each of `Action<string>` and `Action<System.Uri>`.

Now, the C# Language Specification has (among other overloads) these `operator ==`:

```
bool operator ==(object x, object y);                   // §7.10.6
bool operator ==(System.Delegate x, System.Delegate y); // §7.10.8
```

The current Visual C# compiler realizes the first one by simply checking if the references are the same (the IL does not actually call a mscorlib method like `object.ReferenceEquals`, but that would give the same result), while it realizes the second one by calling [`Delegate.op_Equality` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.op_equality.aspx) which looks like a "user-defined" operator inside that assembly even when it is defined by the C# Language Spec, so is maybe not "user-defined" in the sense of the spec(?).

Note that §7.10.8 is a little confusing because it says *"Every delegate type implicitly provides the following predefined comparison operator[s]"* and then gives the operator with the `(System.Delegate, System.Delegate)` signature. That is just *one* operator, not one for "every" delegate type? This seems important for my question.

It is not surprising that the three first `WriteLine` write `False`, `True` and `True`, respectively, given what I said above.

***Question:*** But why does the fourth `WriteLine` lead to the `(object, object)` overload being used?

There does exist an implicit reference conversion from `Action<>` (or any other delegate type) to `System.Delegate`, so why can't that be used here? Overload resolution should prefer that over the `(object, object)` option.

Of course, there are no *implicit* conversions between `Action<string>` and `Action<Uri>`, but why is that relevant? If I create my own class `MyBaseClass` containing a user-defined `operator ==(MyBaseClass x, MyBaseClass y)` and I create two unrelated deriving classes, then my `==` operator will still be used (left and right operand not convertible to each other but both convertible to `MyBaseClass`).

---

Just for completeness, here is the analogous example with **covariance** (`Func<out TResult>`) instead of contravariance:

```
static class ProgramF
{
    static string TargetMethod()
    {
        return "dummy";
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Func<string> instance1 = TargetMethod;
        Func<string> instance2 = TargetMethod;

        Func<ICloneable> f1 = instance1;
        Func<IConvertible> f2 = instance2;

        Console.WriteLine((object)f1 == (object)f2);
        Console.WriteLine((Delegate)f1 == (Delegate)f2);
        Console.WriteLine((Func<string>)f1 == (Func<string>)f2);

        Console.WriteLine(f1 == f2);  // warning CS0253: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right hand side to type 'System.Func<System.ICloneable>'
    }
}
```

A question related to my question above is, *where* in the C# Language Specification does it say that this shall be illegal:

```
Func<string> g1 = ...;
Func<Uri> g2 = ...;
Console.WriteLine(g1 == g2);  // error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Func<string>' and 'System.Func<System.Uri>'
```

I can see that the compiler figured out that no type can ever inherit from both `string` and `Uri` (unlike the pair `ICloneable` and `IConvertible`), and so this (if it were legal) could only become `true` if both variables were `null`, but where does it say that I am not allowed to do this? In this case it would not matter if the compiler chose `operator ==(object, object)` or `operator ==(Delegate, Delegate)` since, as I said, it comes down to checking if both are null references, and both overloads do that in the same way.

Comment: Note that if you create two overloads of a method, one accepting two `Delegate` objects and one accepting two `object` objects, and pass two `Action` objects with different generic types, the `Delegate` overload is chosen, so apparently there is something special about this operator going on, as opposed to general method overload resolution.

Comment: I'm not sure, but just in case, is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939350/implicit-method-group-conversion-gotcha-part-2

Comment: @MatthewWatson Looks pretty closely related, but none of the answers really answer the question of why this happens.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, that looks related. He has compile-time types `System.Delegate` and `System.Action` (he doesn't even need generics to get into trouble), and for him `==` goes to the reference equality overload `(object, object)`. If he casts his `a` such that both operands have compile-time types `Delegate`, the output changes, though.

Comment: Consider `x == y` and the ***compile-time*** types of `x` and `y` (which I shall also call `x` and `y` in this comment). Based on experimentation, it seems this is what happens: (1) If `x` is abstract `Delegate` or `MulticastDelegate` and `y` is abstract `Delegate` or `MulticastDelegate` too, it goes to value comparision. (2) If `x` is a concrete delegate type and `y` is abstract `Delegate` or `MulticastDelegate`, or vice versa, it goes to reference equality. (3) If both are concrete types, and one is implicitly convertible to the other through identity or variance, it goes to value equality.

Comment: ... (4) Otherwise, if both are concrete types, and one is explicitly convertible to the other through identity or variance, it goes to reference equality. (5) If both are concrete types and neither is convertible to the other, it leads to compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: But why does the fourth WriteLine lead to the (object, object) overload being used?

Because it's the only choice for the compiler :-)

```
Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type 'System.Func<System.ICloneable>' and 'System.Func<System.IConvertable>'
```

candidates are:

```
bool==(System.Delegate, System.Delegate) 
bool==(System.Func<System.ICloneable>, System.Func<System.ICloneable>)
bool==(System.Func<System.IConvertable>, System.Func<System.IConvertable>)
```

so using your (object, object) is the best choice the compiler finds.

same for the Actions

```
Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type 'System.Action<string>' and 'System.Action<System.Uri>'
```

candidates are:

```
bool==(System.Delegate, System.Delegate) 
bool==(System.Action<string>, System.Action<string>)
bool==(System.Action<System.Uri>, System.Action<System.Uri>)
```

Comment: But if `==(Delegate, Delegate)` was really a candidate, it should be preferred in all cases over `==(object, object)`. The strange thing is that if you come with compile-time types `(Action, Delegate)`, the compiler acts as if `==(Delegate, Delegate)` did not exist. But if you come with compile-time types `(Delegate, Delegate)` then all of a sudden the C# compiler knows about the `==(Delegate, Delegate)` overload and uses it. Seems inconsequent.